# How to setup a MongoDB replica set for the connector

Tags: mongodb

I want to keep MongoDB and Solr in sync. The mongodb-connector (python) is the tool I want to use to do that. 
Now a replica set in mongodb is required (see [ReadMe](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector)), but I don't want (and can) setup a set/instance.

So can I have a replica set setup with only the primary and without secondaries? Means: A replica set setup with only one instance? And how does this

**Meanwhile I found a solution**:

1. Add in the config-File following:

   - `replSet=rs0` (name is variable) (necessary because starting mongod with replSet option didn't work)
   - `oplogSize=[MemSize]`
2. Start mongodb-instance:

   - `sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start`
   - `mongo`
3. Set replicaset:

   - `rs.initiate({"_id" : "rs0","version" : 1,"members" : [{"_id" : 0,"host" : "localhost:27017"}]})`
   - Check with `rs.status()`

In mongodb 3.2 "replSet" is changed to "replSetName"
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/upgrade-config-servers-to-replica-set/

Answer (score 2):

You can start a single node replica set by starting the `mongod` with the [replSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replSet) argument/config option, that is all that is required.  It takes a name argument, which will then function as the name of the replica set in question.  Once you have done that, you simply run [rs.initiate()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-commands/#rs.initiate) from the shell when connected to the node (this is only needed once).

This is described in detail here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

To stay with just a single node, simply do not follow the "Expanding the set" instructions.

Comment: That didn't work. Meanwhile, I found a solution which is similar to yours: (edit will come soon.)

Comment: Odd, because I have done this maybe.......30 times when testing without a problem, and those are the official docs too

Comment: (See my solution in the question above.)

Comment: your solution is identical to the one I provided, all you did was fill in variable names - if you do not specify an initial replica set name, it is filled in by default as the current process.  Similarly oplogSize is optional - if you do not specify it, it will default to 5% of free space.  Similarly, none of the other commands are optional and are not required to provision an oplog or set up a single node replica set.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did in a similar process for Elasticsearch on a Mac using Brew:

Note: as new daemons are started, switch to new terminals

ElasticSearch (after 'brew install elasticsearch'):

```
$ elasticsearch #start es daemon on port 9200
```

MongoDB just outside the 'data' folder [or other database location] (and after 'brew install mongodb' and 'pip install mongo-connector' and 'pip install elastic2-doc-manager'):

```
$ mongod --dbpath data --replSet "rs0" #create replica set on port 27017

$ mongo #initiate replica set

> rs.initiate({"_id" : "rs0","version" : 1,"members" : [{"_id" : 0,"host" : "localhost:27017"}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @scottlittle answer, how I successfully started the mongodb replica for my local mongodb database by using following commands:

First of all shutdown mongod

```
sudo mongod --shutdown
```

Then run the following commands to run a replica set:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --replSet rs0
```

Make sure that `/var/lib/mongodb/` is your mongodb databases path by using following command

```
grep dbPath /etc/mongod.conf
```

`rs0` will be your replica set name.

Now login to mongo using `mongo` and run following command

```
rs.initiate({"_id" : "rs0","version" : 1,"members" : [{"_id" : 0,"host" : "localhost:27017"}]})
```

It will initiate replica set. Check the status using command if replica set has successfully initialized

```
rs.status().set
```

It should print replica set name e.g. in this case is `rs0`